# Reducing apk size for hybrid apps on Intel XDK

Tags: android, ios, html, hybrid-mobile-app

I started making apps with Intel XDK a while ago and I embraced like if I had no choice the 20+ MB apks, slow app start up and crazy permissions that I didn't ask for.

Searching today for a better css framework to make material design complying apps (I was using Material Design Lite, from google) I found Framework7.

Really neat framework if you ask me, and the showcase is awesome: http://framework7.io/showcase/

Some apps I installed from the showcase range from 988KB to 4MB.

How is that even possible?

I read that HTML5 is one of the most popular language to build apps and I'm doing it completely wrong.

Please, guide me in the right direction for the best practice to make fast and lightweight apps for Android and iOs.

Comment: There are many frameworks for building HTML/JavaScript/css apps. I've used phonegap/Cordova before and am about to loom at react native for a new project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell your experience with the size of the apps?

Comment: Are you using CrossWalk in your XDK apps? That can add weight to your apk. https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/why-use-crosswalk-for-android-builds

Comment: @MorrisonChang, yes I was using it. Now I managed to build an apk with just 1,74MB. Thank you so much! Could you write an answer talking about that and possibly some info on permissions? So I choose your answer as the right one. ;)

Comment: I have been using ionic framework from almost a year and i have no complaints about it. Give it a try!

Comment: @BhavyaKhurjawal thanks for sharing. Have you used to build android apps?

Comment: Yes, You can find it in playstore  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.talkcharge.www&hl=en . My other projects will be soon on playstore too. Ionic is easy and you can find quite a great documentation on their website.

Comment: @BhavyaKhurjawal I will take a look on it for my next projects. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XDK has a feature to easily embedded CrossWalk into your APK. While this does give you a consistent WebView, i.e. your app won't look or act different when running on Android 4.0 vs Android 5.0, it does add to the size of your APK.

Review the documentation on why you should use CrossWalk: [CrossWalk Project FAQ](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html)

**NOTE:** Intel had retired Crosswalk -  [Intel XDK FAQ](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/faqs/crosswalk) and [CrossWalk Final Release](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. About the app permissions, this post says that there is nothing to do about it: https://software.intel.com/pt-br/forums/html5-application-development/topic/532663 :(